# Property 'concatMap' does not exist on type 'Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

Please help, i am trying to send a put request from Angular...when i try to use concatMap i get the error

```
public updateUser(token: string, requestBody: any): Observable<User> {
        const myHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token });
        return this.http.put<User>(this.baseUrl + "api/user", requestBody, { headers: myHeaders }).concatMap(data => {
            return of(data);
        });
      }
```

I get the below error..please anyone knows what i am doing wrong

```
Property 'concatMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<User>'.
```

I have tried the following, nothing worked, still same error

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';

import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: `.pipe(concatMap(..`?

Comment: can u please edit the code lets see?

Comment: oh great i got it now..thanks so much

Comment: can we be friends pls?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding pipe to my code

```
public updateUser(token: string, requestBody: any): Observable<User> {
    const myHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token });
    return this.http.put<User>(this.baseUrl + "api/user", requestBody, { headers: myHeaders })
    .pipe( 
    concatMap(data => {
        return of(data);
    })
);
```

}